# Is $(1,-1,0)$x$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)=(-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2},1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi guys I have a question. $(1,-1,0)$x$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)$=($-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2},1$)?
Thank you.

Comment: No, the cross product of $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0.5,0.5,1)$ is $(-1,-1,1)$.

Comment: I don't think I need to explain... Ivo Terek gave full answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{vmatrix} {\bf i} & {\bf j} & {\bf k} \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 1\end{vmatrix} = \left(\begin{vmatrix}-1 & 0\\1/2 & 1\end{vmatrix},-\begin{vmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1\end{vmatrix},\begin{vmatrix}1 & -1 \\1/2 & 1/2\end{vmatrix}\right) = (-1,-1,1).$$